# Apache Camel JMS Connection to QueueConnectionFactory using Spring

Tags: jms, apache-camel, spring-jms

I was looking through various examples for Apache Camel Jms connection and was trying to figure out if i can
wire in a `QueueConnectionFactory` for a custom Jms provider to my JmsComponent?

So i want to lookup the queue name through jndi
but i have the custom `QueueConnectionFactory` to create the connection
and then from that call `createQueueSession`.

My sudo code is as follows:

```
<bean id="customQueueConnectionFactory" class="QueueConnectionFactoryImpl"/>

<bean id="authenticatedConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
  <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="customQueueConnectionFactory"/>
  <property name="username" value="username"/>
  <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>


<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent"> 
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="authenticatedConnectionFactory"/> 
</bean>
```

This is failing as its not the right way to wire in a QueueConnectionFactory.

```
QueueConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/jms/Connection;
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.doCreateConnection(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:175)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:405)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.establishSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:373)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.establishSharedConnection(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:767)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.doStart(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:280)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.start(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:265)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.start(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:568)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConsumer.startListenerContainer(JmsConsumer.java:105)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConsumer.prepareAndStartListenerContainer(JmsConsumer.java:171)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConsumer.doStart(JmsConsumer.java:155)
```

Any hints? I am using Spring version 3.2.4 & Apache Camel version 2.12.2

Answer (score 1):

camel-jms uses Spring JMS, so you just wireup this the Spring way. At first glance your spring  < bean > looks okay.

Remember to use "jms" as the component name in Camel, as that is the id you gave the component.

Comment: looks like my issues is related to wiring of QueueuConnectionFactory with spring framework. I have added exception details. Am still trying to figure out this.